# Why does my Wordpress index has a category?

Tags: categories

So my homepage is set to display the latest articles of my wordpress site. I use php to detect if the page has a special category in the header of my template and it works on every other pages at the exeption of my homepage that returns the category Blog(ID=12) wich is one of my category. When i go to my phpMyAdmin and look in the wp_term_relationships table I can see 3 posts using this category and they are actual articles. How can I unbind my index page of this blog category?

PS: I'm verry new to this wordpress thing, sorry if I'm unclear.

**This is what's in the head:**

```
<script>
    <?php
    $category = get_the_category();
    if($category[0]->{'name'} !== "Blog"){
        echo "document.onload = removeWhiteDiv();";
    }
    ?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="whiteDiv">
    <pre><?php print_r($category) ?></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: read the Codex https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/ - i.e. you cannot use the function outside of the loop and expect reliable results.

Answer (score 0):

Well I havent found why there's a category to my homepage but I found the  function `is_home()` and added it to my if:

```
if($category[0]->{'name'} !== "Blog" || is_home()){
      echo "document.onload = removeWhiteDiv();";
}
if($category[0]->{'name'} === "Blog" && !is_home()){
      echo "headerAnimation();";
}
```